# Windows hijacked WebStorm's the Ctrl+Shift+N shortcut

Tags: windows-10, webstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

Until a day or two ago I've been able to navigate to files in WebStorm using `Ctrl+Shift+N`. Suddenly today, Windows has hijacked that shortcut and launches a new Edge window.

Any idea how I can override the Windows and use `Ctrl+Shift+N` in WebStorm again?

Answer (score 0):

It ends up the clipboard-history application ClipX has a hotkey of "Navigate" set to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. Setting it to None resolved it.  I've had this application for a long time, I'm still not sure why it's Navigate hotkey suddenly got set, or why it would launch Edge instead of my default browser (Chrome).

Comment: I think hotkeys work in such a way that the first app to register one - gets it and then all other apps that try to register one - fail. Perhaps this one time ClipX started before WebStorm.